# Line separator - JSON to HTML with Angular and pascalprecht.translate

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

Sorry in advance for my bad english..

I have a problem to display a line separator in my HTML page.
I am using AngularJS and the translate module : pascaleprecht.translate. 
I would like to have a Line separator in a translation.

So my angular file is :

```
Betizy.config(function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('fr', {
        'header.betizy': 'BetIzy',
        'header.login': 'Se connecter',
        'header.register': "S'inscrire",

        'login.error' : "Le nom d'utilisateur ou le mot de passe est incorrect.",
        'login.username' : "Nom d'utilisateur",
        'login.password' : "Mot de passe",
        'login.button': "Valider",

        'register.error' : "Une erreur est survenue lors de l'inscription. \u2028 Veuillez contacter un administrateur.",
        'register.username' : "Nom d'utilisateur",
        'register.password' : "Mot de passe",
        'register.email' : "Adresse e-mail",
        'register.button': "Valider"
    });
```

Problem is this line :

> ```
>    'register.error' : "Une erreur est survenue lors de l'inscription. \u2028 Veuillez contacter un administrateur.",
> ```

The result in my HTML page is strange. My line separator is present and recognized by my browser but partially.

Here is my HTML [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2n88.png)

Thank you in advance for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Problem solved by replacing `\u2028` with `<br>` in the translation table, and replacing `{{"'register.error' | translate"}}` with `ng-bind-html="'register.error' | translate"` in the HTML template (see comments).

---

It might be because you've used

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
```

I suggest either removing that line or replacing it with

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitizeParameters');
```

Comment: Thanks you for your response beacuse I forgot to add it but Problem is in the two cases.
With first : 'sanitize', strange symbol was replaced by '&#8232;' .
In the second case : 'sanitizeParameters' it is the same strange symbol.

Comment: You just want to insert a line break between two sentences, is that correct? If so, did you try simply using `<br>` instead of `\u2028`? It works fine (inserts a line break) when `sanitizeParameters` strategy is used. For some reason `\u2028` is invisible for me.

Comment: When i do that, results is : "Une erreur est survenue lors de l'inscription. <br> Veuillez contacter..." So '<br> is not recognized.

Comment: It works ! I had to replace in my HTML page : {{"'register.error' | translate"}} by ng-bind-html="'register.error' | translate".

Comment: Interestingly, using the `translate` directive also works. [Here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1XV8n0w7ZszJ5K87rPa5?p=preview)